# Module reads package from java.xml and stax.api

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, twilio

I am trying to make a javaFX application that can send SMS through a SaaS called Twilio. I am getting an error when I import Twilio onto intelliJ. I am using JDK 11.0.3 and javaFX 11.0.2.

At first I had two projects, one where I created the code to send SMS (as well as other backend logic) and another to create the front-end. Individually they work great, but once I add the SMS code to the front-end project, it stops working.

Error Codes:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream from both java.xml and stax.api
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both java.xml and stax.api
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both java.xml and stax.api
Error:java: module com.google.common reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.google.common reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.google.common reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module failureaccess reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module failureaccess reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module failureaccess reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module listenablefuture reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module listenablefuture reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module listenablefuture reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jsr305 reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jsr305 reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jsr305 reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.checkerframework.checker.qual reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.checkerframework.checker.qual reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.checkerframework.checker.qual reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module error.prone.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module error.prone.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module error.prone.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module j2objc.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module j2objc.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module j2objc.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module animal.sniffer.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module animal.sniffer.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module animal.sniffer.annotations reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module joda.time reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module joda.time reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module joda.time reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jjwt reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jjwt reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jjwt reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module slf4j.api reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module slf4j.api reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module slf4j.api reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module commons.logging reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module commons.logging reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module commons.logging reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.core reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.core reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.core reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jaxb.api reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jaxb.api reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module jaxb.api reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module stax.api reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module stax.api reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module stax.api reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module activation reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module activation reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module activation reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module javafx.swt reads package javax.xml.stream from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module javafx.swt reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module javafx.swt reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both stax.api and java.xml
Error:java: module twilio reads package javax.xml.stream from both java.xml and stax.api
Error:java: module twilio reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both java.xml and stax.api
Error:java: module twilio reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both java.xml and stax.api
```

My module-info if that helps:

```
module MassCommsFrontV3 {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires twilio;

    opens sample;
}
```

I am not quite sure why this is a problem. I have read online that it could have with Twilio's dependencies interfering with my project dependencies, but I'm not really sure what that means.

EDIT: Runtime exception that occurs after deleting module-info:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x1b95c2aa) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x1b95c2aa
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at sample.MainPage.main(MainPage.java:22)
    at sample.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:17)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:28)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: Can you add your pom/build file? At least with the related Twilio dependencies?

Comment: Hi, I would be more than happy to do so but I'm really not sure where those are. I looked them up and it seems I have to make them myself. Is that possible? (I am a beginner so sorry if these steps are evident).

Comment: If you use Maven in your project the dependencies are added to your pom.xml, if you use Gradle, to a build.gradle file. Else you add manually the jars. We need to know what version of Twilio are you using.

Comment: I used maven. But not through the command line, IntelliJ let me do it through its own software if that makes sense. The Twilio version is 7.40.1 (I believe this is the latest one). I was also using 7.39.1 before, but that yields the same results. Let me know if you still need the pom file and thanks for the help!

Comment: If you remove `module-info.java` probably that will solve the issues you are facing. Do you really need to have a modular app (using `module-info.java`)? It looks like twilio dependencies are not modular friendly. Fixing the issues ("split package" related) can be quite difficult if even possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I'm not sure that it is necessary, I was following a tutorial for javafx and it said to create this file. When I remove it, errors pop-up. I'll put an edit in my post to show errors. Is there any way to fix the errors deleting the file creates?

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij (Maven section), you can use the `javafx-maven-plugin` to deal with the JavaFX modules.

Comment: Hi thanks for that response! I am attempting to follow these steps yet I am getting a runtime error when running this (I used maven to create the program). I haven't added any of my stuff yet, I was just trying to see if it would work. Do you happen to know if there's a more beginner version of this? I would not be surprised if my mistake was a rookie one as I am just starting out.

Comment: That is the _beginner_'s guide, so follow each of the required steps carefully.

Comment: That worked thanks! It seems that I was simply setting up my projects incorrectly then.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resolved by Jose Pereda. See comments.